# Function parameters hint for user defined functions?

Tags: autocomplete

```
f1[a_, b_, c_] :=
 Module[{},
  Print[a];
  ]
```

Completion Ctrl-Shift-K doesn't have hint for function arguments.

So I have to copy function arguments nearby:

```
(%a_, b_, c_%)
f1[]
```

Is there is a better way to do this? Maybe I am missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to define its `::usage`

```
f1[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{}, Print[a];]
f1::usage = "f1[a,b,c] prints the first argument";
```

Note that what you write at the beginning at the message (in this case `f1[a, b, c]` ) will determine the completion behavior, which is not defined by the function definition.

Start a new line inside the string to have multiple completion choices.

[image]